# javascript click function displaying the same number

Tags: javascript

I have a simple web page with 5 boxes with number written inside it.
When I click on any box, the number written inside it pops up. But for me same number is popping up.

Here is my JavaScript file:

## main.js

```
var main = function () {
    var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        var num = nums[i];
        var box = $("<div>");
        box.text(num);
        box.addClass("container");
        box.on('click', function () {
            alert("you clicked "+num);
        });
        $('body').append(box);
    }
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

this is my html file:

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>clicker</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my css file:

## style.css

```
.container{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 2px ridge yellow;
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7evx7urg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting the `num` variable that's defined outside of the inner function. Each of these inner functions are pointing to the same `num` variable which changes on each iteration, and which equals 5 at the end of the for loop.  Whenever the anonymous function is called on the click event, the function will reference the same `num`.

The solution for your problem is to use closures. We have to create an inner scope to hold the value of `num` at the exact moment we add the event listener.
here is the solution:

main.js:

```
var main = function () {
    var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        var num = nums[i];
        var box = $("<div>");
        box.text(num);
        box.addClass("container");

        box.on('click', (function (number) {
            return function () {
                alert("you clicked " + number);
            };
        })(num));

        $('body').append(box);
    }
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it has reference to a variable `num`, but the last assigned value to the variable is 5, that's why you're getting always the same number.

Here is the correct code

```
var main = function () {
    var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        var num = nums[i];
        var box = getBoxWithNumber(num);
        $('body').append(box);
    }
};

var getBoxWithNumber = function(num){
                var box = $("<div>");
        box.text(num);
        box.addClass("container");
        box.on('click', function () {
            alert("you clicked "+num);
        });
        return box;
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to move your event binding outside of the `for` loop:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function() {
    alert("you clicked on " + $(this).text());
});
```

I would recommend assigning a class to your dynamically-created `<div>` tags and targeting by that class, so as to avoid an excessive number of alerts.

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/yap0o9ge/